# Could someone explain this interesting ASP.NET HTTP pipeline events behavior?

Tags: c#, events

It is clear that member variables of an ASP.NET page should lose scope every time the page is refreshed.

I have the following code to display a grid of "Alerts" with edit capabilities:

```
public partial class Alerts : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    private _WikiSyntaxEngine;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _WikiSyntaxEngine = new WikiSyntaxEngine();
    }

    protected void gvAlerts_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        var alert = (DataModel.Alert)(e.Row.DataItem);
        // Below is the only line of interest, because only when published
        // to the server would it throw an exception...
        string html = _WikiSyntaxEngine.ConvertWikiTextToHTML(alert.Description);
    }
}
```

It was only on the development server to which I published did this code fail (i.e. throws a `NullReferenceException` because `_WikiSyntaxEngine` was `null`) during an update to the row.

However, on my local machine the code runs just fine - the row is updated and the grid refreshes as expected.

I have since fixed the code to make the `WikiSyntaxEngine` a singleton, or the way it should have been designed from the beginning because it shouldn't have to be instantiated everywhere it is used.

My question then, is how can the `Page_Load` event be called before `gvAlerts_Databound()` on my local machine (as expected), but not called on the development machine resulting in the `NullReferenceException` for `_WikiSyntaxEngine`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that your `gvAlerts` GridView is defined in the ASP.NET markup of the page. If this is the case, it is probably being DataBound in the `OnInit()` event, not on `Page_Load()`, where you're instantiating `WikiSyntaxEngine`.

You probably should use `OnInit()` to instantiate your `WikiSyntaxEngine` if your GridView is getting bound before `Page_Load`.

As for why you're getting different behavior in development and production is still a mystery to me.